# Error adding cordova platform browser, "Error loading cordova-browser"

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-cli

Other platforms are working fine... but I'm having an issue getting browser platform to work at all.

If I run cordova platform add browser it creates the dir, copies all the files, and things mostly looks like it works right except the console outputs "Error loading cordova-browser".

If I then run prepare or anything I get the same error in yellow

> Error loading cordova-browser

If I run cordova requirements... same thing, says Error loading cordova-browser

I'm on Node v6.2.0 and Cordova v6.4.0

--update
 If I keep removing and adding in the platform things seem to work, ts transpiled and everything updated and moved correctly, and I can run from the www folder and everything serves up right. If I just run prepare or build though, the files in platform/browser do not get updated.

Comment: Please try to debug this using and check what is wrong  :

ionic build browser --desktop --testing

Comment: I am getting this error also, and `ionic build browser --desktop --testing` didn't say anything except the `Error loading cordova-browser` message. However, it did update the files in the platform dir, unlike the post author's issue. And all hooks ran as well.

Comment: Yes same here @flanger001, what I've been using in is `ionic build browser --desktop --testing && http-server platforms/browser/www/` which gets the job done well enough, and pulls in everything necessary. I hope it gets resolved so I can use serve with hooks and js though

Comment: Most likely due to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12088

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Cordova CLI 6.5.0 has been released, the error should be fixed

That is just a misleading error message, nothing is really failing and browser platform works just fine.
The issue was [reported](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12088) and [fixed](https://github.com/apache/cordova-lib/pull/506), but not released yet.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem when I upgraded from Cordova 6.3.1 to 6.4.0. Downgrading back to the 6.3.1 seems to fix the problem for me.

Obviously not a long-term solution, but it works for now.

Comment: Was it necessary to downgrade?  I mean, since this is not a real error that causes build problems....