# Cordova : Cordova Browser platform error

Tags: jquery, cordova

Whenever I start application on cmd by cordova run browser, its actually works and load my application into browser but show first log as **Cordova Browser platform error**

Comment: could you brief your problem with elaborate steps?

Comment: do you tried  **Inspect element** in browser? run you app in browser and do right click on browser page and there is option like **inspect element** you will get window and there in console you will get all logs of your app. ( told you about chrome )  or do you have other issue then please write more about your question to get your issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error adding cordova platform browser, "Error loading cordova-browser"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40368353/error-adding-cordova-platform-browser-error-loading-cordova-browser)

Comment: @Gandhi; while targeting Cordova  browser,I'm able to see the application working in the browser but, on the node cmd its showing "Cordova Browser platform error".

Comment: @Naitik: Yes , I'm using chrome's inspect element, the console shows nothing about it. App works fine in browser, but it shows the error on node cmd.

Comment: @pankajshinde Could you post the complete error trace?

Comment: @Gandhi: Only the above console error comes...